# Как в регулярном выражении избавиться от совпадения в альтернативном выборе неявных строк?

Tags: php

```
$array = ['GETST', 'GETT', 'GET', 'POST', 'GPOST', 'GEPOST', 'GETOST'];  
preg_grep('/GET|POST/', $array);
```

Все указанные элементы массива проходят это регулярное выражение.
Как переписать регулярку чтобы могли пройти только `GET` и `POST`?

Comment: обозначить начало и конец строки, не? https://regex101.com/r/q3inWG/1

Comment: Попробуйте [так](https://regex101.com/r/q3inWG/2) - `\b(GET|POST)\b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для ограничения совпадений в шаблоне можно воспользоваться последовательностью символов `\b...\b`, обозначающих **границу слова**, и не сохраняющими скобками `(?:...)`:

```
$array = ['GETST', 'GETT', 'GET', 'POST', 'GPOST', 'GEPOST', 'GETOST'];  
$result = preg_grep('~\b(?:GE|POS)T\b~', $array);

echo '<pre>', print_r($result, true), '</pre>';
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [2] => GET
    [3] => POST
)
```